# Replace function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample text that contains '-' or ' '. So I want a sql `replace` statement that replaces both '-' and ' ' with ''.

My query is:

```
SELECT REPLACE('SQL-Tu torial','-',' ','');
```

Desired outcome:

```
SQLTutorial
```

Error: I get error for Replace function arguments.

> The replace function requires 3 argument(s).

Any help?

Comment: The documentation clearly states that replace method accepts 3 parameters, not 4....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use 3 parameters in a `REPLACE` function. Instead you can use it twice just like below :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('SQL-Tu torial', '-', ''), ' ', '');
```

**Output :**

```
SQLTutorial
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!

Answer (score 6):

Nest two REPLACE functions.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also define a table with all the characters you want to replace and then use a single `replace` statement while selecting from the table:

```
declare @charToReplace table (char_to_replace varchar(1))
declare @tempString varchar(max) = 'SQL-Tu torial'

insert into @charToReplace values ('-'), (' ')

select @tempString = replace(@tempString, char_to_replace, '') 
from @charToReplace

select @tempString as result
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That is _**very**_ cool.  I didn't know `Replace()` would do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than two characters to be replaced, you can use TRANSLATE that came in 2017. Below example replaces "-", " " and "@" with "#" using TRANSLATE and then replaces "#" with "" using REPLACE. I.e., replace "-", " ", "@" and "#" with "". TRANSLATE doesn't buy you anything if you only want to substitute two characters, though.